# Looking for solution file(s)

Tags: php, source-code

I am looking into a website that a coworker created and is used by the business; however, there isn't any documentation on where to find the code for this application. Any suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

nevermind. after a few grep statements and finally waking up i found what i was looking for. Thanks.

in order to find the answer, i first read the little documentation left behind that provided me root access (which helped with a lot of the grep problems). I then grepped for files containing sql statements or something similar. From there I was able to find the location where most of the files were. And viola, I was sitting in the solution.